# How to align right the icon in my ListItem

Tags: android, imageview, listitem

How can i align right the icon in ImageView in my ListView ? I tried gravity="right" but it didn't work. Do i need to add linerlayout specially for it ? Thanks for your help. Below is my code :

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_drawable"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your ImageView in a RelativeLayout and use the code below:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/your_icon" />
```

Hope this is helpful.